# asp.net : How to set client id using DataBinder

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I have the following code in `<asp:Repeater`

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr class="bodyFont">
<td align="left" ><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%></td>
<td align="right"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Percent")%></td>
<td align="right"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Count")%></td>
<td align="right"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Size")%></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

How can I assign client Id to my `<tr>`

I want to hide/show some rows at runtime based on the ID.

Comment: what excatly you want to do with this id?

Comment: what do you mean by client id ? is it a field in your table like status, percent, count and size or something else?

Comment: by client ID i mean id that I can use from javascript on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<%#Container.ItemIndex + 1%>`

Comment: Thanks that give consecutive numbers to my rows, but can i control the Id from server side..

Comment: Yes, you can access Id from server side.

Comment: My statement came out wrong, I wanted to ask if I can assign the ID from my code behind file. ex. for first 5 rows i want it to be normal1...normal 5 then 6th row should be special1 then 7th row onwards i want the id to be extra1.. extra10